# What are up-to-date practises for music mixing for a consistent loudness across different delivery platforms?

Tags: loudness

Loudness management has been a feature of film/tv for a few years now, but streaming platforms are now influencing mixing and mastering practise in the context of loudness normalisation.

What are good practises for achieving loudness normalisation in music mixing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so not a really comprehensive question from me, but really I posted this question simply so that I could forward this link into the stack, which I believe is useful to update people on more up-to-date practises for loudness normalisation and mixing for streaming and content delivery across multiple platforms.

Comment: I enjoyed that clip, some food for thought indeed. Thanks for posting.